# Spark cluster idle most of the time - Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing, databricks

i'm working on several jobs on Databricks, this is one of those, it reads data...and now I dont get what it's doing, no network, no cpu.
The process reads data from a S3 mounted on DBFS, process it and store it on anoter S3 route.
[image: cluster usage]

Went into SQL on Spark UI and see this:
[image: SQL UI]

For ID 12 [image]

For ID 14 is no this step:
[image]

And in Active Stages here:
[image]

On those 10 min...an counting only this on the log:
22/02/10 19:24:20 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0

Any idea of how could I understand what's happening here?
Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution of it?

Comment: for me it looks like some sort of timeout. I usually get this error for almost exact 120 seconds. After that i sometimes see logs like this: "INFO TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to /10.101.13.197:40759, creating a new one."

Comment: It was a MERGE without partition pruning, my bad, looking at it now makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the driver logs of spark - the stderr, stdout and log4j output. It could be a [GC Allocation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426258/spark-nodes-keep-printing-gc-allocation-failure-and-no-tasks-run).

You can also check the executors tab in spark UI. It could give you insights on what part of the code is spark stuck on.